# How to override all link effects?

Tags: html, css, shopify

So I'm trying to edit the Theme of our store on Shopify. I'm doing it in css.liquid under Asset.

Anyway, what I'm precisely doing is I'm trying to override the effect of a link hover (I'm assuming that it is on the theme). Here's a sample of it: https://codepen.io/jstn/pen/mdoOZJ

I've added the following HTML code below:

```
<a href="#" class="a1">Test</a>
```

and on CSS I've added the following:

```
a.a1:hover{
        transition: none;
    }
```

I want to remove those animated underlines when you hover over the links. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you so much in advance! I appreciate it!

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  font: bold 14px/1.4 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
ul { 
  margin: 150px auto 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
li { 
  display: table-cell; 
  position: relative; 
  padding: 15px 0;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    ul {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underline is being created with the `a:after` pseudo-element. To override it, this should suffice:

```
a.a1:hover:after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: or simply remove the `a:after` rule completely

Comment: Of course; I was assuming that modifying the original style sheet wasn't an option. But if it is, by all means remove those `:after` rules.

Comment: a good point well made!

Answer (score 0):

So the transition is caused due to the transition on pseudo element `a:after`. To change this behaviour just set `transition: none;` on **a:after**

Here's what I mean:

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  font: bold 14px/1.4 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
ul { 
  margin: 150px auto 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}
li { 
  display: table-cell; 
  position: relative; 
  padding: 15px 0;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: none;
  width: 0;
}
a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    ul {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```